# Detectar pistas de audio de video

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hola chicos que tal estoy creando un reproductor con html css y javascript, pero tengo el problema que cuando uso un link dual audio (esp - ing) no emite ningun sonido. Como podria o que codigo podría ejecutar para que el reproductor detecte las diferente pistas de audio y me de la opción de elegir.

Se lo agradeceria muchisimo a quien pueda ayudarme. Si necesitan el codigo haganmelo saber. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bien, tengo en enlace mp4 de video, es cual el dual audio. Tiene una pista en español y ingles, estoy creando un reproductor usando html css y javascript. Lo que solicito y lo que me gustaria hacer es lograr que el reproductor detecte las pistas de audio, y me de las opciones. 

Cuando uso el link dual, no emite ningun sonido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoría tendrías que ocupar [AudioTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioTrack), en donde la documentación de mozilla detalla lo siguiente

> The most common use for accessing an AudioTrack object is to toggle
> its enabled property in order to mute and unmute the track.

Traducción

> El uso más común para acceder a un objeto 'AudioTrack' es alternar su
> propiedad 'enable' para silenciar y reactivar la pista

Que es justamente lo que necesitas !!!!

Lamentablemente la compatibilidad de esto es demasiado pobre para que tenga alguna utilidad real

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando información adicional encontré blogs del 2011 hablando de la salida de esta API, es decir han pasado más de 10 años y no hay implementación global. Incluso Edge antes la soportaba y con el cambio de motor que tuvo ahora ya no la soporta. Así que pocas posibilidades de que en un futuro próximo esto se pueda lograr.

Comment: Gracias amigo, esta bastante complicado lograr la función